# change thread user in java

Tags: java, multithreading, permissions

I run my java program as USER_1 under Windows. I need my program to make a thread with USER_2's permission.

I have no idea how to do it. Searching the web for hours didn't yield me any answers.

How about Thread.setDaemon(true/false)? Would it help anyway?

Answer (score 4):

Well, your google must be different then, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014691/can-i-switch-user-on-runnable-thread-in-java?rq=1). Short answer; no you can not.

Users are bound to processes. Threads aren't separate processes as far as the OS is concerned.

Comment: How about an administrator parent, making a child thread with a user permission?

Comment: @Pazis How would that change the fact that users are bound to processes, not threads?